# Ajax prevent default and submit form on current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following script, which works perfectly BUT the problem is I need a `form action attribute` for it to work, thus my question how can I modify my current script that it prevents default form submit behaviour and **submits form on current page without the need for an `action attribute` in form**

```
$(function() {
  var form = $('#editRes');
  var formMessages = $('#formMsg');
  // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
  $(form).submit(function(e) {
    // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
    e.preventDefault();
    //do the validation here
    if (!validateLog()) {
      return;
    }
    // Serialize the form data.
    var formData = $(form).serialize();
    // Submit the form using AJAX.
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: $(form).attr('action'),
      data: formData
    }).done(function(response) {
      // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
      $(formMessages).removeClass('error').addClass('success');
      // Set the message text.
      $(formMessages).html(response); // < html();
      // Clear the form.
      $('').val('')
    }).fail(function(data) {
      // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
      $(formMessages).removeClass('success').addClass('error');
      // Set the message text.
      var messageHtml = data.responseText !== '' ? data.responseText : 'Oops! An error occured!.';
      $(formMessages).html(messageHtml); // < html()
    });

  });
  function validateLog() {
    var valid = true;
    //VALIDATE HERE
    return valid;
  }
})
```

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get you. Can you please explain what you want ?

Comment: Hi @mrid my script only works with `<form action="page.php">` BUT when I have a form like `<form action="">` i.e. submitting form with script on page without `action` attribute included in form field my script doesn't work....Makes sense?

Comment: Use input type button instead of submit. Register an click event on that button and remove your $(form).submit() function. $(button).click() will remove your action attribute.

Comment: Try `url: $(form).attr('action') || window.location.pathname,`

Comment: I think because you are using form action as url in AJAX parameters. So, since the action is empty it can't take the url.

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax, you are using `url: $(form).attr('action')`. This means the form will get submitted to whatever is the `action` attribute of your form. Since there is none, the ajax will not work.

If you want the form to be without an `action` tag, you can just write the form submit url (*page.php*) in the ajax url part

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'page.php',
    data: formData,
    ...
    ...
});
```

Comment: No need of action attribute. Remove submit and use type="button" and register click event on this button. Ajax url will be value of action attribute.

Comment: Sorry I dont get you `you can just write the form submit url (page.php)` can you please expand.... @TechBreak I cant remove my submit button

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee why you can't? Any specific reason? As per your question you want to submit form on current page.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to `window.location.href`.

Side-note: You do not need to rewrap `form` in `$()` as it is already a jQuery object in your second line -- same goes for `formMessages`.

```
$(function() {
    var form = $('#editRes'); // this is a jQuery object 
    var formMessages = $('#formMsg'); // this is also a jQuery object

    // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
    form.submit(function (e) {
        // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
        e.preventDefault();
        // do the validation here
        if (!validateLog()) {
            return;
        }
        // Submit the form using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: window.location.href,
            data: form.serialize()
        }).done(function(response) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
            formMessages.removeClass('error').addClass('success');
            // Set the message text.
            formMessages.html(response); // < html();
            // Clear the form.
            $('').val('')
        }).fail(function(data) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
            formMessages.removeClass('success').addClass('error');
            // Set the message text.
            var messageHtml = data.responseText !== '' ? data.responseText : 'Oops! An error occured!.';
            formMessages.html(messageHtml); // < html()
        });
    });

    function validateLog() {
        var valid = true;
        //VALIDATE HERE
        return valid;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your submit function add:

```
return false;
```

This will prevent to browser from navigating away.